# Tapestry5 - squash bean properties into one grid cell

Tags: java, datagrid, grid, javabeans, tapestry

i don't know if this is possible to do using Tapestry5.
I would like to squash some bean properties into only one grid cell.
For example, take a look at this bean :

```
public class BeanExample {
       private int x;
       private int y;
       private String string;
       //getters, setters etc..
}
```

If i would show this bean using a default grid it will generate something like this :

```
    X   |   Y    |   STRING
___________________________
    0   |   1    |   hello
    1   |   4    |   by
```

What i would like to do is to "squash" two properties into only one and show it at FrontEnd like this :

```
    X   |   Y+STRING
___________________________
    0   |   1 / hello
    1   |   4 / by
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of hiding the `string` column and providing a custom `block` for the `y` cells. See the [grid javadoc](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Grid.html) for more info

```
<t:grid source="rows" exclude="string" row="current">
    <p:yCell>
        ${current.y} / ${current.string}
    </p:yCell>
</t:grid>
```